# can d3.js/JavaScript lookup the date and find the value linked to that date?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've created a dashboard through using d3.js and I thought I had finished but it turns out that the static example data that I had been given is different to what the actual data is now  the system is about to go live.

I'm loading the data from an csv for this I'm looking to find the budget for the correct month. This specific data is not being used to create the chart that is separate data completely this is being used so that under that graph I can have text elements saying things like `Total sales Today = £80,000` for example. The old data I was given was in this format:

```
Target
9999999
```

So I this is the code I had for that data:

```
d3.csv("data/OrderValueTarget.csv", function(obj) { 

var text = 'Budget = £';
var targetSales = text + d3.format(',')(obj[0].Target);

svgLabel = d3.select("#label2").append("h2")
    .text(targetSales)
});
```

Which works great when the data was in the older format however now that data has changed quite a bit. This is what it looks like now for example:

```
Month,Target
APR,2222221
MAY,2222222
JUN,2222223
JUL,2222224
AUG,2222225
SEP,2222226
OCT,2222227
NOV,2222228
DEC,2222229
JAN,2222220
FEB,2222221
MAR,2222222
```

So what I've been asked to do is have something that can look up the month we are in and change the value to the corresponding month. So is there any way I can do that within d3/javascript? So if I wanted to Months budget from SEP its would just say `Budget = £2222226`

Thanks

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be to have an object with the names of the months as keys and the respective values. Then you can simply do `object[month]`.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff Would this do it dynamically though so when we went to a new month would it switch to that month? if not is there a way that this is possible? Thanks

Comment: Well every time the month is changed, you would need to retrieve the current value.